# Global meteor collection in closure for Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

If I declare a global collection as below:

```
@Matches = new Meteor.Collection "Matches"
```

How can I find a consistent way to access it in a closure on both the server- and client-sides of Meteor?

For example, the below doesn't work, since `@` refers to `this` (which is not the top-level namespace in the closure)

```
Meteor.publish("current-matches", ->
  return @Matches.find(round: 0)  # @Matches doesn't work since `this` is something else
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your collection definitions in a shared directory so they will be seen by both the client and the server. You can then use them without the `@`. For example:

**collections/matches.coffee**

```
@Matches = new Meteor.Collection 'matches'
```

**server/server.coffee**

```
Meteor.publish 'current-matches', ->
  Matches.find round: 0
```

Comment: Just a sidenote not to use `Match` as a name. `Match` is a defined thing in meteor: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/match_test Yeah, I know, you used `Matches` ...